# Error: Could not find or load main class - Youtube Data API example

Tags: java, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have downloaded the client library from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/)

And placed all the required `.jar` files in the `libs` folder.

I then downloaded [Search.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/youtube/api-samples/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java) example (mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples)) and [Auth.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/youtube/api-samples/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java)

I was able to successfully compile `Search.java` and `Auth.java`, but when
I try to run it, I get this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class [class name]`

I have tried the following:

- `java com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.Search`
- `java Search`

I still get the same error.

Current directory:

```
.
├── Auth.java
├── libs
├── Search.java
└── youtube.properties

1 directory, 3 files
```

After compiling:

```
.
├── Auth.class
├── Auth.java
├── libs
├── Search$1.class
├── Search.class
├── Search.java
└── youtube.properties

1 directory, 6 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you compile those files? You need to locate `Search.class`. If there's `package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data` declared in the file, then file iself should live in `/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/` folder, and same would be true for the `.class` file once compiled. And you should then invoke `java` command from the location where such folder path starts.

Or alternatively you use some IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans or other to import sample as project in there and let IDE take care of resolving all correctly.

Comment: I had no idea that that if its part of a package it must be in a specific set of folders, let me try this, thanks!

Comment: Simply do not declare package - remove from the source line that starts with `package com.google...` and recompile it again.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out